# Windows 7 Pro aero glass remoting - any hacks to enable it?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop and Aero in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/78709/remote-desktop-and-aero-in-windows-7)

Hi!

1. Is there any hacks that allowes Aero *Glass* Remoting (From Windows 7 Pro) *to* my Windows 7 Pro?
2. I presume there is also patch for Windows 7 Pro that allows using the computer *and* remoting the same computer at the same time. (Similar concurrency patch was for 7 RC, Vista and XP so I'm pretty confident I find this)

See also this [table in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_Professional).

Comment: Both questions have duplicates. http://superuser.com/questions/78709/remote-desktop-and-aero-in-windows-7  http://superuser.com/questions/62178/multiple-rdp-sessions-on-a-single-computer

Comment: @heavyd, I read the first thread before posting... and what I understod their outcome was that when remoting *to* Windows 7 Pro the aero does not work (only when remoting *to* Ultimate/enterprise it works).

Comment: @heavyd, And second doesn't mention anything about Windows 7, from what I know it Concurrency thing cannot be done with simple registry edit, one needs to patch the dll like in Windows 7 RC and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you expand Options, in particular the `Experience` tab and choose `Desktop Composition`, it should allow remote Aero.

This is built in to the latest version of Remote Desktop / Terminal Services Connection, and you should only need to install an update on older versions - it does not require any "hack".

[image]

Comment: I believe you, just update this table then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_Professional I cannot update it yet as I cannot test it until I have the Win7Pro installed...

Comment: "it should allow remote Aero." doesn't allow it for me, i'd say the wiki update will have to wait :)

Comment: @Molly - What do you mean? I shouldn't of written the word should, this is the correct way to do it - if the version of Windows you connect to allows it, this is how to view it remotely.... @Ciantic, try it - it does work in ANY version of 7 that has Aero and remote desktop.

Comment: He likely means when you go `Personalize` screen, the Window Color has 1 option, Windows 7 Basic, the Windows aren't transparent.  Yes this is even with `Desktop Composition` enabled.  I can get Remote Aero Glass with Win7Ultimate in VMware Workstation, but I cannot get it in Win7Pro.

Comment: "Aero glass remoting" is feature not available in Windows 7 Pro. I think, it is responsible for screen recording software to be able record content of window in background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to clarify what you mean by Aero Remoting.  Do you mean Aero *Glass* Remoting or just Aero Remoting?

Type `allow remote access` or you can find `Remote` tab of `System Properties`.  I believe by default `Remote Assistance` is turned on, and `Remote Desktop` is turned off.

If you have older RDP clients (Windows XP machines) you'll want to the less secure option.

If you have the latest RDP client, and if you're using Win7 Pro to connect to Win7 Pro, you should have it, you'll get Aero Remote, it won't be Aero *Glass* Remote unless you remote into Win7 Ultimate/Enterprise system.

What is the difference?  Glass is the semi-transparent window borders, and snazzy UI widgets.  Glass is Flip3d and AeroPeak.  Glass is being able to play a multimedia video through the remote session with sound that doesn't look like it is running on a 486DX (this is also a bandwidth intensive so you want to do this on the LAN).

First Google hit of `windows 7 concurrency remote desktop` comes up with:

> http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm
>
> http://www.missingremote.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=3293&Itemid=232

Caveat, haven't tested this out since I haven't really needed this.

Comment: Sir, Aero Glass Remote, this is most likely what is meant with Wikipedia table too... And thats what I'm asking, there must be a hack  that allows Win7Pro -> Win7Pro Aero (Glass) Remoting.

Comment: I updated the question, now it is hopefully more clear.

Comment: Please read the comment in my answer, I do not know why Wikipedia has that chart - but, following my answer should allow aero through the way I said.

Comment: That chart is correct for RTM.  I have tested against Win7 Pro and Win7 ultimate.  If you remote *into* Win7 Pro, you won't get transparent windows, and the `full Aero experience`.  You need to remote *into* Ultimate/Enterprise.  Even if you click every checkbox before you remote in, you still won't get it.  The Wikipedia page has citation, please cite yours.